# Regarding Web Services C# ho to pass argument from input

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api

I want to figure out how can I pass value from input to web services using c#? I have code:

**Animal.aspx:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelForType" runat="server" Text="Animal Type"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="AnimalType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text="Animal Type"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

**Animal.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void AddAnimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientService service = new ClientService();

            service.getAnimalType();


        }

        public String getAnimalType()
        {
            return AnimalType.Text.ToString();
        }
```

**Web services. ClientService.asmx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
        public String getAnimalType()
        {

            return animal.getAnimalType(); 

        }
```

Unfortunately it does not work. If I send my input value as a parameter to a web service. I can type whatever in soap window but it will not return the value which I typed in input. Any ideas? Or maybe there is a tutorial? Thank you.

**I am looking how to pass the value from textbox ID="AnimalType" to WebServices. If type Chicken it should pass chicken to web services.**

*Basically. Create value - > Send it from C# as a parameter to Web Services - > Took that value in Java by calling to Web Services.*

I made like.

```
private String type;

        public void setAnimalType(String typee)
        {
            type = typee;  
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public String getAnimalType()
        {
            return type;
        }
```

But it returns null.

Comment: `"If I send my input value as a parameter to a web service"` - Where are you trying to do that?

Comment: I tried. Instead of. public String getAnimalType()
        {
            return AnimalType.Text.ToString();
        }


I can put. service.getType(String AnimalType.Text.ToString())

But it does not change cause in xml Soap I can write whatever to invoke another type of animal but it does not take the type that I put into input.

Comment: Are you just asking how to add a parameter to a `WebMethod`?  Something like: `public String getAnimalType(int someTypeID)`?  Or whatever the parameter type and name should be.  Then you'd use that parameter to determine what you should return.  It's really not clear what the problem is here.  It sounds like what you're looking for is an introductory tutorial on ASP.NET Web Methods.

Comment: I am looking how to pass the value from ID="AnimalType" to WebServices.
If type Chicken it should pass chicken to web services.

Comment: In the web service method you'd add that as a parameter, such as `string animalType`.  However you *invoke* the web service (which isn't shown here), you'd pass that value with the key "animalType".  (Or you can change the name of the method parameter and thus the name of the key when calling the web service.)

Comment: But when I will want to call to that method (this one is in java).

proxy.getAnimalType(//here I don't want to send any parameters). It jus had to return what I sent from C#.

Comment: So... You want the web service to *receive* a parameter, but you don't want to have to *send it* a parameter?  That doesn't really make any sense.  I'm afraid it's not clear *at all* what you're trying to do or what isn't working.  Can you take some time and more clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish in the question?

Comment: It's very simple. I don't understand what is not clear :D. The thing is I want to send as parameter to Web services with C#. Later on take that value from Web services in JAVA.

Basically. Create value - > Send it from C# as a parameter to Web Services - > Took that value in Java by calling to Web Services.

Comment: Ya, that's not a clear description at all.  Nothing about what you just said makes sense to me.  How is Java even involved here at all?  You have an HTML page (for the most part) and a C# web service method.  There are no "parameters" anywhere in your C# code.  We've shown you how to add some, but you're claiming that isn't what you're looking for.  So I'm afraid you're fundamentally failing to describe what it is you *are* looking for.

Comment: Updated post added some code. But somehow it still does not want to work as it should .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
private String type;

public void setAnimalType(String typee)
{
    type = typee;  
}

[WebMethod]
public String getAnimalType()
{
    return type;
}
```

It makes all the sense in the world from a *strictly* object-oriented point of view.  *However*, when you're in the context of ASP.NET there are some subtleties of the framework and the stateless nature of HTTP which change things.

In short, every time you invoke your ASP.NET "page", a *new instance* of that page's class is created.  So any class-level values you set on previous instances are gone.

You need to persist that value somewhere.  There are many options:

- A `static` variable
- Session state
- A cache somewhere
- A database
- A file
- etc.

The ASP.NET page objects are stateless.  With every request an instance is created, interacted with, and destroyed.  Values which need to persist across multiple requests need to be persisted outside class-level instance members in this case.

Comment: Finally Fixed with static variable. !!

Comment: @user2204367: Glad to hear it!  Be aware of other implications of that, though.  Multiple users on the site/service at the same time would all be setting the same static variable.  So they may over-write each other.

Answer (score 1):

Change you service method to take parameters as follow

```
[WebMethod]
public String getAnimalType(string animal)
{
    //Do something with the param
    return "something";
}
```

Then call your service like

```
ClientService service = new ClientService();
var animalType = service.getAnimalType(AnimalType.Text);
```

Comment: But man then I can write whatever in soap as a parameter. But I need that method would return what I typed into input. Later on I am using those services in java. 

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
  ClientServiceSoapProxy proxy = new ClientServiceSoapProxy();
  
  System.out.println(proxy.getAnimalType() + " " 
  + proxy.getAnimalRegNr() + " " + proxy.getAnimalWeight());
 }

Comment: Take a look at the updated snippet above, it'd send whatever is typed in the textbox

Comment: But when i call to that method from java it requires to send a parameter. But which Actually I don't need. :/